# wpf how to use jpg from resource in xaml-image?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

In my c#/WPF project, I added a jpg to the resources to embed into the exe file.

Now I want to use this jpg in an image tag, something like

```
<xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:MyProgram.Properties"
<Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource prop:LogoJpg}}"
```

My problem: it does not work. I got no idea, how to use the image. I could use files from the hdd, but I need the image to be embedded in the exe file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add the image to your project, with a Build Action of "Resource" (not EmbeddedResource).  For instance, I've added an image called "logo.jpg" to a folder called Images in my main project.

Then, in XAML, you use just use that resource as follows:

```
<Image Source="Images\logo.jpg" />
```

You can also use the [pack syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the source:

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/logo.jpg"  />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But what if the image is available only in the form of an embedded resource?

Comment: this syntax worked for me while designing a Start Page for Vs.net 2010, however, when deployed, the image didn't show. any ideas?